# React Native White labeling Remove unwanted code

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-router, react-hooks, white-labelling

I am creating react native application which required to do white labeling for that i have planned using react-native.config. Using that config package we are able to achieve white label in android and iOS.

Now, client has multiple application and if we are submitting that application even with different package name , different icon and image the binaries will be same size and there is chance that application will reject when we submit to App app store and google play store due to that ( as mentioned in 4.2.6 point here : https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/). I am planning to do something like exclude different variant code at build time so, binary of the application will be different for each variant of my build.

Anyone please suggest how can i achieve this or any other work around to do this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just exclude it at runtime?

Comment: yes, runtime is done using "react-native.config" package but it will include JS code in final package and because of that code is also include for all white-label packages. and as we have previous experience in native application Apple is rejecting it due to same binary file.